# Android - Trouble passing variables between activities using intents

Tags: android, class, variables, android-intent

I'm new to Android and I'm just trying to pass two doubles from one activity to another. This question has been asked several different times on this site in several different ways, but something about my implementation is causing my app to force close. I think my problem may be with my "savedInstanceState" Bundle in the activity I'm trying to pass the variables to. I left out a lot of code obviously, but I included all the places where Bundles are used.

[EDIT] - I found a bad programming solution for what I need to do. I put public static variables in the receiving class and access them from the sending class. I realize this is bad programming, but it does what I want. Thanks to all who tried to help. I'm going to continue to try to do this the proper way.

Without the i.putExtra lines and any lines involving the Bundle extra, it works fine.  Here's the code:

```
int lat = 0;
int lon = 0;
private void createNote() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    i.putExtra("lat", lat);
    i.putExtra("lon", lon);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}
```

This is the activity I sent them to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    int lat = extra.getInt("lat");
    int lon = extra.getInt("lon");

mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null : (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID) : null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();
}

private void saveState() {
    String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
    String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();
    String lattitude = mLatText.getText().toString();
    String longitude = mLonText.getText().toString();
    String date = mDateText.getText().toString();
    String time = mTimeText.getText().toString();

    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body, lattitude, longitude, date, time);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body, lattitude, longitude, date, time);
    }
}
```

Comment: With what error is you app getting force closed... and at which line?

Comment: @raju is right: you have to include a logcat trace if you want any accurate suggestions.

Comment: You sure you are correct in passing a float and retrieving an integer?

Comment: 04-24 15:57:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.meh.tabbedlayout/com.meh.tabbedlayout.NoteEdit}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should pass values.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("str1", str1);
bundle.putInt("int1", int1);
bundle.putDouble("double1", double1);
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(i);
```

And this is how you get them in next activity

```
int int1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("int1")
String str1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("str1")
double double1 = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("double1")
```

does this clear your doubts?

Comment: I did this but it still force closed. I tried adding one line at a time and then running it, and I found that I can create a Bundle and add variables to it, but when I add i.putExtras(bundle) it force closes. Do you have any idea why that would cause problems?

Comment: then I think it is better if you post logcat entries here. That might give us a clue as to where the error is. What error does logcat show anyway? Null pointer ??

Comment: Yes sir/mam, it actually is a Null pointer. 

04-24 15:57:32.162: E/AndroidRuntime(631): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.meh.tabbedlayout/com.meh.tabbedlayout.NoteEdit}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: The problem seems to be in createNote, updateNote or your SQLite retrieval methods of your DBHelper Class. Cursor out of bounds exception is not related to passing values between activities or using bundles. please check mDBHelper and Data retrieval methods.

Answer (score 0):

The looks fine, you problem is someplace else.
Try adding prints before setting the intent to make sure your key and value are what you really think they are

Answer (score 0):

```
int name = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(key);
```

You are calling `startActivityforresult`.so try getting the bundle in `onActivityResult` not in `oncreate`.you can override this `onActivityResult`

- I think this is the problem try getting the bundle using this.you will get the value to this new variable.